# Conformal mapping of the intersection of two ellipses

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Can the region between intersection of two ellipses or circles (looks like a crescent) be mapped on to a rectangular region or any other simple region? And is there a systematic way to determine the mapping function to map an arbitrary region to a simple region like rectangle or a disc?

Comment: The short answer is yes, this is the Riemann Mapping Theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem

Comment: It will be quite difficult to find a formula for the map, though. For a general domain, there is no systematic way of doing this, other than numerically.